# LIKE BUTTON - Where to start

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a custom button in simple HTML for webmasters and site owners to add on their websites which will display the number of time that web page was "LIKED". Like the way Facebook does it but without authentication.

I have created an API which

1. You can send a URL and can GET the like counter in INT (API will match the URL in my SQL database and will return the like counter)
2. You can send a URL and can SET the link counter  (API will match the URL in my database and will increment the counter by +1)

http://localhost:88899/api/V2/HITS/GET?URL=https://forum.xda-developers.com/
http://localhost:88899/api/V2/HITS/SET?URL=https://forum.xda-developers.com/

My API doesn't use the authentication but it does use the API Key to not get blasted by unwanted requests to the server.

I don't know where to start with the client side, how does the Facebook do it, Looking at it, passing the URL returns the total number of likes for that page.

**CODE**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

**Results**

[image]

Surprisingly it also applies the facebook CSS styling.

I know it is an extremely generic question but where do I even start?

Cheers

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots. Paste it into your question (preferably as a working example, SO has a js-fiddle-ish editor built-in).

Comment: what really is your problem? is it the styling for the "LIKE" button?

Comment: `I don't know where to start with the client side` what do you mean ? Isn't your browser your client ?!

Comment: @GeomanYabes I want to create a LIKE button for my product, so when its clicked - Just like facebook or Google+ etc They all have buttons

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer code added, thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching for the documentation? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#example

Comment: @GeomanYabes i think i didn't explain really well, I dont want to use Facebook like button but i want to create my own for my app - Facebook is javascript to connect to thier API (js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";) i want to connect to my API and get results from my database

Comment: first of all - **why C#** ? Is your api in c# for should your client (containing your button be C# (like winforms or wpf). ?

Comment: @FelixD. yes you are right, it wont be in C#, it will be in simple Javascript / HTML

Comment: well you should update your tags then.. really confusing :P

Comment: @FelixD. done  , i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is actually very simple.

1. The code part is used to "inject" the js script used to make the calls and display the counter, add the CSS classes, etc...
2. The HTML part is used to display the data from the "injected" js script.

Now, the "injected" script should work with no requirements on the page that is using it (jQuery for example).

In your script you can have a self invoked function to simulate "document ready" event in jQuery after the script is downloaded and loaded by the browser or you can create a queue like Google analytics does and store your commands you want to run when the script is loaded.
To make "ajax" calls you can use `XMLHttpRequest` to access your API methods.

Comment: thank you so much for the direction, i am just thinking about the API KEY, if i public the API key then whats the point of having an API KEY and if i remove the API KEY authentication from my API then how would i know the API calls are really made from the script i provided and now random DDOS

Comment: Yeah, you can generate a "client key" and use that in your script as config setting and API calls to validated the client and prevent malicious calls.